# Magento Soap V2 API - 'The requested Payment Method is not available'

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2

I am trying to create an order using the payment method code 'checkmo' which is in the example documentation but I am receiving the error "The requested Payment Method is not available.". Please see my code below:

```
<?php
//*** GLOBAL VARIABLES ***//
    $client = new SoapClient('URL');
    $session_id = $client->login('User', 'Pass');


//*** CREATE ORDERS ***//
    //foreach ($line as $iLineNumber => $data_line) {
    try {
            $cartId = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session_id, 1);
            $customerList = $client->customerCustomerList($session_id, array());
            $customer = (array) $customerList[0];
            $customer['mode'] = 'customer';
            $client->shoppingCartCustomerSet($session_id, $cartId, $customer);
            $productList = $client->catalogProductList($session_id);
            $product = (array) $productList[653];
            $product['qty'] = 1;
            $client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session_id, $cartId, array($product));

            $address = array(
                array(
                    'mode' => 'shipping',
                    'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
                    'street' => 'street address',
                    'city' => 'City',
                    'region' => 'Region',
                    'telephone' => 'phone number',
                    'postcode' => 'LN2 4FX',
                    'country_id' => 'United Kingdom',
                    'is_default_shipping' => 0,
                    'is_default_billing' => 0
                ),
                array(
                    'mode' => 'billing',
                    'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
                    'street' => 'street address',
                    'city' => 'City',
                    'region' => 'Region',
                    'telephone' => 'phone number',
                    'postcode' => 'LN4 2FX',
                    'country_id' => 'United Kingdom',
                    'is_default_shipping' => 0,
                    'is_default_billing' => 0
                ),
            );
             // add customer address
            $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($session_id, $cartId, $address);
            // add shipping method
            $client->shoppingCartShippingMethod($session_id, $cartId, 'flatrate_flatrate');

            $paymentMethod =  array(
                // 'po_number' => null,
                'method' => 'checkmo',
                // 'cc_cid' => null,
                // 'cc_owner' => null,
                // 'cc_number' => null,
                // 'cc_type' => null,
                // 'cc_exp_year' => null,
                // 'cc_exp_month' => null
            );
             // add payment method
            $client->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session_id, $cartId, $paymentMethod);
             // place the order
            $orderId = $client->shoppingCartOrder($session_id, $cartId, null, null);
            echo 'Success: Order has been created: ', $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo 'Error: Order could not be created: ', $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
        }
    //}
?>
```

Could anybody save me here? Thank you.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Nothing yet unfortunately.